# Turning off the "'register' storage class specifier is deprecated" warning

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, boost, xcode5

With the recent Xcode 5.1 update we're getting a bunch of new warnings in our code base -
this is apparently related to an updated version of clang that [now warns](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=184068) about usages of the `register` storage class specifier in C++11 sources as [it has been deprecated with C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

```
/Users/me/Documents/Sources/boost/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:288:9: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated
```

Now we'd like to suppress the warning for code that we cannot change - like the BOOST sources in the example above.

I could find the compiler flag to turn the warning on (`-Wdeprecated-register`) but is there an opposite to disable the warning from the Xcode settings..?

Comment: One possible solution could be to send a report to the boost guys to stop using `register` and other deprecated things :P

Comment: Yeah... I guess we could just wait couple years for that to happen for ALL boost libs ;-)

Comment: @KitsuneYMG ..that one actually results in **compiler errors**, i.e. the `register` keyword is no longer recognized at all..

Comment: @Jay `-Dregister=`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In general, prepending `no-` to an option turns it off. So if `-Wdeprecated-register` enables the warning, then `-Wno-deprecated-register` should disable it.

Alternatively, on many compilers you can use pragmas (or similar) in your code, to disable warnings while including particular headers while leaving them enabled for your own code. They are compiler-specific; for Clang, it's something like

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-register"
#include "dodgy.hpp"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

(For GCC, the pragmas are the same, only replacing `clang` with `GCC`. I don't know about any other compilers.)

Answer (score 10):

This also works

```
#if __cplusplus > 199711L
#define register      // Deprecated in C++11.
#endif  // #if __cplusplus > 199711L
```

Answer (score 9):

Suppressing the warning is the wrong tool here. Use the `-isystem` flag when including code that is not yours and it will generate no warnings in that code.

Comment: Nice trick, though `-isystem` is too broad for our purposes: we need to specifically turn off *just* the register warning.

Comment: In Xcode warnings are disabled on project level. In that particular project all 3rd party libs are located. Stuff other than boost in that project we'd like to keep an eye on and not just ignore all warnings. Not every 3rd party lib goes through a thorough peer-review process like the boost libs so better make sure..